# Set to null JSF spinner

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spinner

In this project I am using spinner from jsf primefaces library.
I'm trying that when textbox is cleared the value is set to null, however it always set the minimum value defined.

Somebody can give me a hint or direction?

I was trying to make something with onBlur event but it didn't workout.

Comment: Looking at the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/spinner.xhtml) code, I see they've backed the spinner with an `int`, or `double`, which cannot be `null`: they're not objects. Even if you used `Integer` or `Double` I'm not sure how the PrimeFaces' developers will handle the validation and display of `null`. You might try setting it to a value user's can't select, like `-1` if the min is 0.

Comment: @davids: where do you see PrimeFaces is used?

Comment: @Kukeltje, good point, I just assumed it was PF.

Comment: Standard JSF doesn't have any spinner component. Perhaps you meant to say PrimeFaces? It's most widely used JSF component library and indeed has such one component. Edit and improve your question to make that more explicitly clear.

Comment: Hi BalusC. Yes the question is related to PrimeFaces. Sorry for not referring that.

Comment: After editing my question, to turn it about Primefaces. has anyone any  hint'??? Thanks

Comment: Is the lowest value for the spinner a valid value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : This should prevent `0` to be affected to the variable when leaving empty in the view, and then set it to `null`.

```
<h:outputLabel for="spinner1" value="Enter an integer : " />  
<p:spinner id="spinner1" value="#{bean.number1}" >  
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.spinner1Changed}" />
</p:spinner>
```

With :

```
Integer number1; //  + getter/setter

public void spinner1Changed(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    if (number1 == null) number1 = null;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, and number1 value when spinner1changed is invoked is actually null,but this code, doesnt change the content of the text box.